# ML.Net image classification could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member

Tags: c#, .net, onnx, ml.net

I am trying to use ML.Net to load an onnx model and make image classification from in-memory images. As usual with ML.Net things seems to be complicated where it should be easy.

I can't seem to find how to change the input class to use in-memory images instead of loading them from file.

So far I have :

```
public class InputData
{
    [ImageType(720, 1280)]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately it gives me the `Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member Image Arg_ParamName_Name` error when trying to call this :
`var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(Array.Empty<InputData>());`

The whole point is simply to get a prediction engine. The whole code looks like so :

```
public class InputData
{
    [ColumnName("Image")]
    [ImageType(720, 1280)]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
}

public class OutputData
{
    [ColumnName("dense")]
    public float[] Scores { get; set; }
}

public PredictionEngine<InputData, OutputData> Initialize(string path)
{
    //Create MLContext
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

            
    int size = 224;
    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "image", imageWidth: size, imageHeight: size, inputColumnName: "Image")
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "image"))
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel("dense", "image", path, fallbackToCpu: true));

    var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(Array.Empty<InputData>());

    var model = pipeline.Fit(data);

    var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<InputData, OutputData>(model);

    return predictionEngine;
}
```

After two dozen google research I'm out of ideas!

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found that with ML.NET 2.0 in order to get rid of the system drawing dependencies, a new image type MLImage was created.  You use this object almost the same way like BitMap in your example, but I'll alter it to illustrate.

```
public class InputData
{
  [ImageType(720, 1280)]
  public MLImage Image { get; set; }
}
```

When you create the enumerable data object I think your method will still work, but I used:

```
var data = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List<InputData>());
```